# How to translate with Scrapy and DeepL API?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, deepl

### How can I translate the items `['devicecount']` and `['released']` using the DeepL API?

---

Here is my code:

```
import scrapy
from gsm.items import GsmItem

class GsmSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'gsm'
    allowed_domains = ['gsmarena.com']
    start_urls = ['https://gsmarena.com/makers.php3']

    # LEVEL 1

    def parse(self, response):
        
        item = GsmItem()

        gsms = response.xpath('//div[@class="st-text"]/table//tr[1]//td[1]')
        for gsm in gsms:
            allbranddevicesurl = gsm.xpath('.//a/@href').get()
            brandname = gsm.xpath('.//a/text()').get()
            devicecount = gsm.xpath('.//span/text()').get()
            
            item['brandname'] = brandname
            item['devicecount'] = devicecount

            yield response.follow(allbranddevicesurl, callback=self.parse_allbranddevicesurl,
                                    meta= {'brandname': item,
                                           'devicecount': item})

    # LEVEL 2

    def parse_allbranddevicesurl(self, response):
        
        item = response.meta['brandname']       
        item = response.meta['devicecount'] 

        phones = response.xpath('//*[@id="review-body"]//li')
        for phone in phones:
            detailpageurl = phone.xpath('.//a/@href').get()

            yield response.follow(detailpageurl,
                                    callback=self.parse_detailpage,
                                    meta= {'brandname': item,
                                           'devicecount': item})

        next_page = response.xpath('//a[@class="pages-next"]/@href').get()
        if next_page is not None:
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse_allbranddevicesurl,
                                    meta= {'brandname': item,
                                           'devicecount': item})

    # LEVEL 3

    def parse_detailpage(self, response):
     
        item = response.meta['brandname']       
        item = response.meta['devicecount']
         
        details = response.xpath('//div[@class="article-info"]')
        for detail in details:
            phonename = detail.xpath('.//h1/text()').get()
            released = detail.xpath('.//ul/li[1]/span[1]/span/text()').get()             

            item['phonename'] = phonename
            item['released'] = released

            yield item
```

---

**I would appreciate an example of how to access the values stored in the items and pass it to a translation function.**

---

Comment: Your question is quite confusing - what is an item in this case? Are you referring to the scrapy response object? Try giving an example to better convey your point

Comment: I have adjusted the question according to the suggestions. Thanks to @victor__of__doom

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think what you are trying to do is to translate the values keyed by 'devicecount' and 'released'? According to [the scrapy API](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html), ```Request.meta``` (which has been largely replaced by ```Request.cb_kwargs```) is just a dictionary. Couldn't you just access the values stored in the dict and pass it to a translation function? At that point you'd have a string.

Answer (score 1):

Based on our exchange in the comments, it seems like the following function would satisfy your needs:

```
    import deepl, scrapy
    from typing import *
    from gsm.items import GsmItem
    
    AUTH_KEY = <YOUR_AUTH_KEY>

    class GsmSpider(scrapy.Spider):
        name = 'gsm'
        allowed_domains = ['gsmarena.com']
        start_urls = ['https://gsmarena.com/makers.php3']

        def translate_vals(data: Dict[str, str], keys: List[str], lang: str)-> Dict[str, str]
    
        T = deepl.Translator(AUTH_KEY)
        return {k: T.translate_text(text, target_lang=lang) for k,v in data.items() if isinstance(v, str) and v in keys}
    
        # LEVEL 1
    
        def parse(self, response):
            
            item = GsmItem()
    
            gsms = response.xpath('//div[@class="st-text"]/table//tr[1]//td[1]') # one brand --> adjust tr[1] & td[1]
            # gsms = response.xpath('//div[@class="st-text"]/table//td')         # all brands
            for gsm in gsms:
                allbranddevicesurl = gsm.xpath('.//a/@href').get()
                brandname = gsm.xpath('.//a/text()').get()
                devicecount = gsm.xpath('.//span/text()').get()
                
                item['brandname'] = brandname
                item['devicecount'] = devicecount

                translate_vals(item, ['brandname', 'devicecount'], 'fr')

                yield response.follow(allbranddevicesurl, callback=self.parse_allbranddevicesurl,
                                        meta= {'brandname': item,
                                               'devicecount': item})
    
        # LEVEL 2
    
        def parse_allbranddevicesurl(self, response):
            
            item = response.meta['brandname']       
            item = response.meta['devicecount'] 
    
            phones = response.xpath('//*[@id="review-body"]//li')
            for phone in phones:
                detailpageurl = phone.xpath('.//a/@href').get()
    
                yield response.follow(detailpageurl,
                                        callback=self.parse_detailpage,
                                        meta= {'brandname': item,
                                               'devicecount': item})
    
            next_page = response.xpath('//a[@class="pages-next"]/@href').get()
            if next_page is not None:
                yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse_allbranddevicesurl,
                                        meta= {'brandname': item,
                                               'devicecount': item})
    
        # LEVEL 3
    
        def parse_detailpage(self, response):
         
            item = response.meta['brandname']       
            item = response.meta['devicecount']
             
            details = response.xpath('//div[@class="article-info"]')
            for detail in details:
                phonename = detail.xpath('.//h1/text()').get()
                released = detail.xpath('.//ul/li[1]/span[1]/span/text()').get()             
    
                item['phonename'] = phonename
                item['released'] = released
    
                yield item
```

Then you'd just call it like `translate_vals(Request.meta, ['devicecount', 'released'], 'fr')` (for example). You can sign up for a free DeepL `AUTH_KEY` [here](https://www.deepl.com/pro#developer).

Comment: Okay, I added it.